# Unable to send email from localhost using gmail smtp?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp, gmail

I am looking into cakephp email component first time. I am sending email like this from my localhost:

```
    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(  'port'=>'465',
                                        'timeout'=>'30',
                                        'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                                        'username'=>'mygmail@gmail.com',
                                        'password'=>'mygmailpassword'
                                     );


    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    $this->Email->from = "mygmail@gmail.com";
    $this->Email->to = "yourgmail@gmail.com";
    $this->Email->subject = "Subject";
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
    $this->Email->lineLength = 255;
    $body = "<h1>This is body</h1>";
    $this->Email->send( $body );
```

It is not sending any email or not even showing any error.

Is there something missing ?

Thanks

Comment: check out google account for smtp enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail's SMTP server requires SSL if I recall correctly.

Try

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'port'=>'465', 
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username'=>'your_username@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'your_gmail_password',
);
```

Comment: I have tried this before but not sending. I removed it because I don't have ssl installed on my localhost.

Comment: Read http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287 - SSL must be used to use the GMail SMTP server. Quote: "If your client does not support SMTP4 authentication, you won't be able to send mail through your client using your Gmail address."

Answer (score 2):

Host should be : `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: I have tried this before but not sending. I removed it because I don't have ssl installed on my localhost.

Comment: Have you tried to uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your php.ini ?